# How to test whether a token variable exists?

Tags: expl3, latex3

`expl3` provides predicates to test whether variables of various data types exist, e.g. `\cs_if_exist:NTF`, `\tl_if_exist:NTF`, `\str_if_exist:NTF`, `\int_if_exist:NTF`, etc. However, I couldn't find a similar function for the data type `token` (Part XV in the Interfaces3 documentation). So How can I test whether a token variable exists (for instance, one that was possibly created using `\token_new:Nn`)?

Here's a use case. Whenever I write LaTeX3 functions that take parameters, first thing I do inside the function's body is name the parameters, i.e. I initialize local variable with the raw parameters `#1`, `#2`. After this point I never use the raw parameters again; only the named variables.

So suppose I wish to write a function, `\g`, that takes a single argument that should be of type "function variable" that may or may not be defined, and then I wish to test whether this variable is defined. So `\g`'s structure would be something like this:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \g #1
{
    \token_new:Nn \f {#1}
    \token_if_exist:NTF \f {...} {...}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Except `\token_if_exist:NTF` is not available from `expl3`.

Comment: I don't think that's what `token` is for (I guess there `\cs_set_eq:NN` and `\cs_if_exist:NTF` is the logical answer), but I'm not capable of answering with security. In any case, I remember that you have been told that the declarations `_new:` should *not* be inside of a function; and I see that you keep writing `_new:` statements inside of functions, why?

Comment: On the question itself: `\token_new:Nn` is mainly for saving 'copies' of character tokens. It therefore doesn't have unique 'place' to put tokens. I'm not sure how the result of your proposed `\token_if_exist:N(TF)` differs from `\cs_if_exist:N(TF)`, other than that presumably the former should allow character tokens.

Comment: @JosephWright: The problem with the `\cs...` functions is that I cannot assign to a variable of type `cs` an argument that is a control sequence that may not be defined. So in the above example, I couldn't make `\f` a variable of type `cs`.

Comment: I've moved the 'general `expl3`' comments to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67221/discussion-on-question-by-evan-aad-how-to-test-whether-a-token-variable-exists): I've retained those that seem directly focussed on the question.

Comment: @EvanAad Are you sure you can't `\cs_set_eq:NN \f \whateverundefined`?

Comment: @Manuel: No, I'm not sure. In fact, now that I've tested it, this might be a good solution to my problem, at least insofar as my use case is concerned.

Comment: Probably worth noting here is that the `token` functions are somewhat 'under-reviewed' compared to other parts of the code: several of them are 'cool ideas' or similar that may not fit that well with the longer-term aims of the team.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are not really any 'token variables': the `l3token` module is a set of low-level functions for 'token stuff', reflecting the fact that TeX works with tokens and so we sometimes need to think at this level.

We cannot create/manipulate for example a letter token in the same way we can a `cs` token, so it is not really clear what `\token_if_exist:N(TF)` might do. For example, for a Unicode engine we can have the 'existence' of 1000s of character tokens, but presumably this is not what is to be tested. As such, it is very likely the case that `\cs_if_exist:N(TF)` will provide here the same useful information.

---

If you wish to store the exact token passed in a variable, you need to do that using a `tl`: this is irrespective of the nature of the argument. Thus we might have

```
\tl_new:N \l__my_tmp_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \my_demo:N #1
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__my_tmp_tl {#1}
```

Later, if you want to know if the `cs` given as `#1` is defined, and if you don't want to just use `#1`, you'll need to get the value back from the `tl

```
\exp_after:wN \cs_if_exist:NTF \l__my_tmp_tl
```

Note that as `\cs_if_exist:NTF` needs the `cs` 'as is', I've had to use `\exp_after:Nw` to expand the `tl`. Personally I'd stick to just using `#1` but this is ultimately your call!

---

Notably, `l3token` has not to-date (October 2017) been reviewed as carefully as some other parts of `expl3`.  This review work has taken place as use of `expl3` has spread and the ideas have therefore had a good 'airing'. It is likely that the team will look over `l3token` in the near future, and it is quite possible that some functions will be removed/altered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67238/discussion-between-joseph-wright-and-evan-aad).